# How to link to an issue on GitHub, including the issue status

Tags: github, markdown

I'm looking for the markdown syntax to do this:

[image]

I'd like to create a nice link that includes the issue status (here, it's the green symbol). I could not find this documented anywhere and my Google skills are failing me. It seems to be a highly guarded secret for the high priests to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls#issues-and-pull-requests) says:

> If you reference an issue, pull request, or discussion in a list, the reference will unfurl to show the title and state instead. For more information about task lists, see "[About task lists](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-task-lists)."

For example:

```markdown
- #1
```

or

```markdown
- [ ] #2
```

are both OK.

Comment: It has to be in a list! Thanks. But why would they require a list?

Comment: @boot4life I don't know either. The question may, can be answered only by an GitHub employee...